# Value is not updating in the browser

Tags: angular

I have a member:

```
airline = 'string';
```

And in my template I have:

```
<p>{{airline}}</p>
```

This obviously shows `string` in the browser.

I have a function:

```
setValue(selectionChangedEvent) {
  this.airline = selectionChangedEvent.selectionChanges[0].selected[0].properties.airline;
  console.log(this.airline);
}
```

This function is called from:

```
this._map.on('SelectionChanged', function (selectionChangedEvent) {
  if (selectionChangedEvent.selectionChanges.length > 0) {
    var c = new MapComponent();
    c.setValue(selectionChangedEvent);
  } else {

  }
});
```

When I run the code, I do see the value of `this.airline` in the setValue function, but the value in the browser is still `string`.

Why is it not updating in the browser?

Comment: Are all the functions in the same component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a new component with

```
var c = new MapComponent();
```

So your original value never gets updated. You probably want to use

```
this.setValue(selectionChangedEvent);
```

instead, but therefor you also have to save the context by changing to a lambda function

```
this._map.on('SelectionChanged', (selectionChangedEvent) => {
```

Otherwise this.setValue won't exist since you are in the wrong context.

Comment: Oh yea, of course. I create a new component but never pass the value. I'm not sure what a lambda function is, have seen it in Java, but not really used it. But your suggestion fixed the code. Cheers.